# Preencher data.frame usando saidas de um for

Tags: python, r, for, data.frame

Queria saber como aplicar a logica do R no Python.
Por exemplo: Se eu entrar com o codigo abaixo no R:

```
x <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:10) {
  x[i,1] <- i
}
```

Ele ira criar no data.frame x uma coluna, e irá preenche-la com os numeros de 1 a 10, e acabara criando 10 linhas
Gostaria de aplicar a mesma logica no python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode criar o data frame dessa forma, passando o range como valor e como index:

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.DataFrame({'v1':list(range(1,11))}, index = list(range(1,11)))
x
```

Saída:

```
   v1
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
```

Pode criar a lista de  valores e depois usar:

```
import pandas as pd
valores = list(range(1,11))
x = pd.DataFrame({'v1': valores}, index = valores)
x
```

Saída:

```
   v1
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
```